# SliverAppBar in reversed CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter

I am building a chat `app` and I want new chat messages arrive from the bottom of the `SliverList`. As well I want the `SliverAppBar` to scroll out of view (floating) when the scroll view starts scrolling when enough messages have arrived.

I am using a reversed `CustomScrollView` with an `SliverAppBar` and a `SliverList`:

```
CustomScrollView(
                keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
                reverse: true,
                controller: _scrollController,
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (context, index) {
                        return _messages[index];
                      },
                      childCount: _messages.length,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SliverAppBar(
                    title: Text('Chat App'),
                    centerTitle: true,
                    floating: true,
                  ),        
                ],
              ),
```

This way the `SliverAppBar` is on top of the `SliverList`, but not at the top of the screen. Is it possible to set the `SliverAppBar` to the top of the screen as if it was not reversed?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no... I switched back to a normal Scaffold AppBar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      body: NestedScrollView(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return [
            const SliverAppBar(
              title: Text('Chat App'),
              centerTitle: true,
              floating: true,
            )
          ];
        },
        body: ListView.builder(
          reverse: true,
          // shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return _message(20 - index);
          },
          itemCount: 20,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _message(int index) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
      height: 60,
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Message $index'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]